# Set screen autorotation system setting from code

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out how to modify this setting programmatically. Could someone indicate an API or suggest something?

The images illustrate where this option is in Android:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you want to do this for you application, or for you entire OS?

Comment: The solution I'm trying to make the code should have the same behavior of the option mentioned in the image. I do not want to configure the application to prevent the screen from rotating, is not it. I would like to enable or disable the option mentioned only.

Comment: Hi tolgap, for you entire OS.

Comment: I don't think that is allowed, what you can do is to redirect them to the settings page.

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION

And here is the code for you

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
android.provider.Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION,1);
```

And this permission required in Manifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />`

Comment: Perfect. :) Added permition: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

Answer (score -1):

If what you are trying to do is lock your application in a specific screen orientation, you can use the `android:screenOrientation` attribute in your activity's manifest.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen).

Comment: Dave, that's not what I would do. See the comments.